# Codeigniter - Login is not working in the if part

Tags: php, codeigniter

My login is not working when I input the data it will always revert to login view... I create it so it will go to front/home if I input the data but somehow the if in function login is not working and always change it to the else...

**Controller:Login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
    $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
    $this->load->model("Member_model");
}

public function loginMember() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('front/login');

    } else {

        //enter username and password
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('Member_model');
        $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password);

        if ($member) {

            $id_member = $this->Member_model->get_member_id_from_username($username);
            $member    = $this->Member_model->get_member($id_member);

            //set session variables
            $_SESSION['id_member']   = $member->id;
            $_SESSION['logged_in']   = true;
            $_SESSION['username']    = $member->username;

            //redirect
            redirect('Member/profile');

        } else {

            print_r('User doesnt exist');                
        }
    }
}

//logging out of a user
public function logoutMember() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true) {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        }
        redirect('Member/Login');
    }
}
```

}

**Controller:Member.php**

```
 public function profile() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] !== true) {

        $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Please login first to view");
        redirect('Member/Login');
    } else{
        $this->load->view('front/home');
    }
}
```

**Models:Member_model.php**

```
     public function checkLogin($username, $password) {

    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('member');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');

    return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);
}

public function get_member_id_from_username($username) {

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('member');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);

    return $this->db->get()->row('id');

}

public function get_member($id_member) {

    $this->db->from('member');
    $this->db->where('id', $id_member);
    return $this->db->get()->row(); 
}

private function hash_password($password) {

    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   
}


private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash) {

    return password_verify($password, $hash);   
}
```

**View:login.php**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Login/loginMember'); ?>" >                        
                        <input class="text" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your username"><br>
                        <input class="text" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    </form>
                    <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="<?php echo site_url('Member/Register'); ?>"> SignUp NOW!</a></p>
```

I think the problem is in this code:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('front/login');

        } else {

            //enter username and password
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $this->load->model('Member_model');
            $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password);

            if ($member) {

                $id_member = $this->Member_model->get_member_id_from_username($username);
                $member    = $this->Member_model->get_member($id_member);

                //set session variables
                $_SESSION['id_member']   = $member->id;
                $_SESSION['logged_in']   = true;
                $_SESSION['username']    = $member->username;

                //redirect
                redirect('Member/profile');

            } else {

                print_r('User doesnt exist');                
            }
        }
```

Because, after I input the data it will print out User doesnt exist... Eventhough the data that I input it's seems like the data that in database..

Comment: you really need to go through codeigniter's docs. You're clearly not doing it the right way as written by the framework. Why use a framework and still use PHP's `sha1()` function??

Comment: you are wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

In the Member Controller change the if condition. You forgot a "=" in it.

```
if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE)
```

And check if your session variable stores the data.

Comment: it still not function

Comment: Did you check value of $_SESSION['user_logged']  after setting it? may be using $_SESSION['user_logged'] = "true" might be useful if you want to echo it

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: I already change $_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE to $_SESSION['user_logged'] == TRUE but it still print out eror

Comment: You are using $_SESSION['user_logged'] in Member controller while you set $_SESSION['logged_in'],  the variables are different

Comment: Yes, I already change it... but the problem is in the if($member) when I comment this and put redirect (member/profile) bellow $member = $this->Member_model->checkLogin($username, $password); it worked fine... I think the if function on the login Member is not function right

Comment: $this->form_validation->run($this) doesn't need '$this' inside run()

Comment: in checkLogin in the model, did you check if you are getting the password field data from db? It seems like password_verfy is failing, like you give wrong username and password

Comment: i use $this in the form because it cannot be read if i'm not inputting $this on that... And yes I already checked teh password and it seems